# GNOME on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 i cant install GNOME 3 on it. I want it to look like version 10.04 or 9.04. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the classic GNOME look, you need to install `gnome-session-fallback`. If you want the GNOME 3.x look, you need to install `gnome-shell`.

Note however, all of the same applets are not available for the 3.x version of gnome-panel, and you may have had some added to your panels which are no longer available.

Comment: I install gnome 3 with sudo apt-get install gnome-core

Comment: @Andrew The gnome-core package was a GNOME 1.x package, and was meant to be a transition package when it went away in GNOME 2.x. I'm not sure why the package is still around as a meta/transition package, but you probably shouldn't use it exactly.